# How can an organization query Azure DevOps API to get a list of all users' associated projects and/or teams?

Tags: security, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

There are many conventions for user, group, and team management in Azure DevOps available. Despite having business standards, we see our administrators inconsistently using the different methods, resulting in orphaned accounts, unmanaged permissions, etc.

Is there a way to query the Azure DevOps REST API services to get a list of all user accounts within an Organization, and the list of Projects, Teams, Groups, Roles they are member within?

I imagine this would take more than one API request, so a full solution is what we are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

First method: **list all projects**, filter based on user list:

```
projects = GET https://dev.azure.com/{orgname}/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0
results = []
foreach project in projects:
    descriptor = GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{orgname}/_apis/graph/descriptors/{project.id}
    members = GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{orgname}/_apis/graph/users?api-version=6.0-preview.1&scopeDescriptor={descriptor}
    if userId in members:
        results.push(project)
```

Second method: **get user entitlements**

This is better because this will show all projects that people have Reader (or higher) on, where the first method doesn't show projects where the user doesn't have explicit membership

```
users = GET https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{orgname}/_apis/UserEntitlements?$filter=name eq '{userId}'&$orderBy=name Ascending&select=Projects
user = [x for x in users where x.userId == userId][0]
results = user.projectEntitlements
```

Note the [select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user-entitlements/search-user-entitlements?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) query parameter included in the second example, this is necessary for `projectEntitlements` to be included in the result.